# Printing by monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a BIXOLON mobile printer, I can print by this device in windows mobile programs.
I want to print by this device in MONODOIRD applicaiton...
there is sdk, but the lib that use that sdk is java...
is any body know how can I print by this device in monodroid?!

Comment: finnaly I print by sending command directly to device
this is a [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582101/printing-with-android/14318577#14318577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your "lib" is a `.jar` file? If it is, [bind it](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29), which will make it accessible from C#.

Comment: Ok. I will check it and informe you... thns for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

after I read xamarin help about bindding jar file, I get some errors....
I listed in the end of this post...
I need this jar file compile completly...

Warning 1   missing class error was raised while reflecting com.bixolon.android.library.BxlService : android/hardware/usb/UsbManager

Warning 2   missing class error was raised while reflecting 
com.bixolon.android.library.UsbLauncher : android/hardware/usb/UsbManager

Warning 3   For ConnectThread, could not find enclosing type 'BxlService'.

Warning 4   For ConnectThread, could not find enclosing type 'BxlService'.

Warning 5   For ConnectedThread, could not find enclosing type 'BxlService'.

Warning 6   For ConnectedThread, could not find enclosing type 'BxlService'.